# Delete multiple files from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a list of files like this:

```
**SAN-20160424-113635.nc**  
SAN-20160424-233507.nc
SAN-20160424-113739.nc  
SAN-20160424-233757.nc
**SAN-20160424-113843.nc**  
SAN-20160424-233902.nc
SAN-20160424-113947.nc  
SAN-20160424-234006.nc
**SAN-20160424-114237.nc**  
SAN-20160424-234110.nc
```

And I would like to keep just all of them which are multiple of 4 (as shows in the list) and delete the others. How could I do this from terminal or bash?

I have a bunch of files and I want to do it automatically

Thanks.

Comment: what is multiple of 4?

Comment: What have you tried?  And it seems like you wan tto delete "every 4th" file (starting with the first), but how are you ordering these?

Comment: looks like he want keep "every 4th"..

Comment: Sorry, what I meant with "multiple of 4" was every 4th file from the list. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GNU `sed`, you can use `~` to denote "every n-th line". `1~4` in the address means "starting from line 1, taking every 4th". To get the list of files to delete, just remove these:

```
sed '1~4d' list
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```
perl -nlE 'say if ($.-1)%4' < list_of_files.txt
```

will print the list for the delete, e.g.

```
SAN-20160424-233507.nc
SAN-20160424-113739.nc
SAN-20160424-233757.nc
SAN-20160424-233902.nc
SAN-20160424-113947.nc
SAN-20160424-234006.nc
SAN-20160424-234110.nc
```